# Combinator Reduction Wolfram Mathematica

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica, logic, discrete-mathematics

How can I implement the normal reduction strategy for Combinators {S,K,I} in Mathematica?
Here are the rules: 
S[x][y][z]->x[y][z[y]]
K[x][y][z]->x

Also we have an Y combinator ( fixed point)  thus Y[a]=a[Ya]].

And we must "evaluate" the expression like ,for instance, S[K][K][a] = K[a][K[a]]=a

It is highly important to have a ONE step of reduction. Thus, that the result will be in application one step many times..

Thanks in anticipation for any suggestions!!!

Comment: There's also [a Mathematica Stack Exchange site](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) for Mathematica questions.

Comment: There are typos in the definitions of `S` and `K`.  They should be: `S[x][y][z] -> x[z][y[z]]` and `K[x][y] -> x`.  Oh, and brackets missing in `Y[a] -> a[Y[a]]`.

Comment: Thanks, you'll right about missing brackets. It's seems to me very problematic to use such simple rules, because in this way Mathematica itself determine the way to apply them, but it's highly important to me to use them in special order-- in applying to left outermost redex each time

Answer (score 7):

Let's define a function called `eval` that will perform one step of combinator evaluation. First, we need to consider what exactly constitutes a single step. Arbitrarily, we will evaluate the left-outermost expression first and work inwards from there.

```
ClearAll[eval]
eval[e_] := Module[{r = eval1[e]}, r /; r =!= e]
eval[e:f_[g_]] := Module[{r = eval[f][g]}, r /; r =!= e]
eval[e:f_[g_]] := Module[{r = f[eval[g]]}, r /; r =!= e]
eval[e_] := e
```

Note that the rules are only applied if they actually change the expression. The awkwardness of these definitions is due to Mathematica's lack of a pattern expression that will match arbitrarily long curried argument lists.

Now we can define the recognized combinators, *S*, *K* and *I*:

```
ClearAll[eval1]
eval1[s[f_][g_][h_]] := f[h][g[h]]
eval1[k[f_][_]] := f
eval1[i[f_]] := f
```

The symbols are in lower case here mainly to avoid the way that Mathematica renders the built-in symbol `I`, the imaginary unit.

Any other combinators will be taken as variables and left unevaluated:

```
eval1[e_] := e
```

Now we can try out the basic cases:

```
i[f] // eval

(* f *)

k[f][g] // eval

(* f *)

s[f][g][h] // eval

(* f[h][g[h]] *)
```

For more interesting cases, let's define `evalAll` that shows all steps in an evaluation chain:

```
ClearAll[evalAll]
evalAll[e_, n_:Infinity] := FixedPointList[eval, e, n+1] // Most // Column

s[k][k][a] // evalAll 

(*
s[k][k][a]
k[a][k[a]]
a
*)

s[s[m][n][r]][k[a][b]][c] // evalAll

(*
s[s[m][n][r]][k[a][b]][c]
s[m][n][r][c][k[a][b][c]]
m[r][n[r]][c][k[a][b][c]]
m[r][n[r]][c][a[c]]
*)

f[s[i[k]][k][g][i[f]]] // evalAll
(*
f[s[i[k]][k][g][i[f]]]
f[i[k][g][k[g]][i[f]]]
f[k[g][k[g]][i[f]]]
f[g[i[f]]]
f[g[f]]
*)
```

`evalAll` takes an optional "count" argument to limit the number of steps shown.  This is useful for divergent expressions -- like a direct expression of the *Y* combinator:

```
eval1[y[f_]] := f[y[f]]

y[f] // evalAll[#, 4]&

(*
y[f]
f[y[f]]
f[f[y[f]]]
f[f[f[y[f]]]]
f[f[f[f[y[f]]]]]
*)
```

... but it is more fun to express such sequences in terms of *SKI*:

```
Module[{y = s[k[s[i][i]]][s[s[k[s]][k]][k[s[i][i]]]]}
, evalAll[y[f], 28]
]

(*
s[k[s[i][i]]][s[s[k[s]][k]][k[s[i][i]]]][f]
k[s[i][i]][f][s[s[k[s]][k]][k[s[i][i]]][f]]
s[i][i][s[s[k[s]][k]][k[s[i][i]]][f]]
i[s[s[k[s]][k]][k[s[i][i]]][f]][i[s[s[k[s]][k]][k[s[i][i]]][f]]]
s[s[k[s]][k]][k[s[i][i]]][f][i[s[s[k[s]][k]][k[s[i][i]]][f]]]
s[k[s]][k][f][k[s[i][i]][f]][i[s[s[k[s]][k]][k[s[i][i]]][f]]]
k[s][f][k[f]][k[s[i][i]][f]][i[s[s[k[s]][k]][k[s[i][i]]][f]]]
s[k[f]][k[s[i][i]][f]][i[s[s[k[s]][k]][k[s[i][i]]][f]]]
k[f][i[s[s[k[s]][k]][k[s[i][i]]][f]]][k[s[i][i]][f][i[s[s[k[s]][k]][k[s[i][i]]][f]]]]
f[k[s[i][i]][f][i[s[s[k[s]][k]][k[s[i][i]]][f]]]]              <-- f[...]
f[s[i][i][i[s[s[k[s]][k]][k[s[i][i]]][f]]]]
f[i[i[s[s[k[s]][k]][k[s[i][i]]][f]]][i[i[s[s[k[s]][k]][k[s[i][i]]][f]]]]]
f[i[s[s[k[s]][k]][k[s[i][i]]][f]][i[i[s[s[k[s]][k]][k[s[i][i]]][f]]]]]
f[s[s[k[s]][k]][k[s[i][i]]][f][i[i[s[s[k[s]][k]][k[s[i][i]]][f]]]]]
f[s[k[s]][k][f][k[s[i][i]][f]][i[i[s[s[k[s]][k]][k[s[i][i]]][f]]]]]
f[k[s][f][k[f]][k[s[i][i]][f]][i[i[s[s[k[s]][k]][k[s[i][i]]][f]]]]]
f[s[k[f]][k[s[i][i]][f]][i[i[s[s[k[s]][k]][k[s[i][i]]][f]]]]]
f[k[f][i[i[s[s[k[s]][k]][k[s[i][i]]][f]]]][k[s[i][i]][f][i[i[s[s[k[s]][k]][k[s[i][i]]][f]]]]]]
f[f[k[s[i][i]][f][i[i[s[s[k[s]][k]][k[s[i][i]]][f]]]]]]       <-- f[f[...]]
f[f[s[i][i][i[i[s[s[k[s]][k]][k[s[i][i]]][f]]]]]]
f[f[i[i[i[s[s[k[s]][k]][k[s[i][i]]][f]]]][i[i[i[s[s[k[s]][k]][k[s[i][i]]][f]]]]]]]
f[f[i[i[s[s[k[s]][k]][k[s[i][i]]][f]]][i[i[i[s[s[k[s]][k]][k[s[i][i]]][f]]]]]]]
f[f[i[s[s[k[s]][k]][k[s[i][i]]][f]][i[i[i[s[s[k[s]][k]][k[s[i][i]]][f]]]]]]]
f[f[s[s[k[s]][k]][k[s[i][i]]][f][i[i[i[s[s[k[s]][k]][k[s[i][i]]][f]]]]]]]
f[f[s[k[s]][k][f][k[s[i][i]][f]][i[i[i[s[s[k[s]][k]][k[s[i][i]]][f]]]]]]]
f[f[k[s][f][k[f]][k[s[i][i]][f]][i[i[i[s[s[k[s]][k]][k[s[i][i]]][f]]]]]]]
f[f[s[k[f]][k[s[i][i]][f]][i[i[i[s[s[k[s]][k]][k[s[i][i]]][f]]]]]]]
f[f[k[f][i[i[i[s[s[k[s]][k]][k[s[i][i]]][f]]]]][k[s[i][i]][f][i[i[i[s[s[k[s]][k]][k[s[i][i]]][f]]]]]]]]
f[f[f[k[s[i][i]][f][i[i[i[s[s[k[s]][k]][k[s[i][i]]][f]]]]]]]] <-- f[f[f[...]]]
*)
```

Comment: In response to @Anna's clarifications as to desired evaluation order, I have changed the code from "applicative order of evaluation" to "normal order of evaluation".  I had originally implemented the former as it shortened the derivations that I was using as test cases, and also the resulting derivations matched the sources I was consulting when composing this response.  I have still made some arbitrary choices concerning evaluation order, but hopefully I have shown how the code can be tweaked if other choices are desired.